# Loading Newly Installed PHP Module Into Apache

Tags: php, apache, imap

I am working to build a small email client inside a web application. After doing some research I attempted to use the imap function. I got an error saying I was calling an undefined function, so again I researched and uncommented `extension=php_imap.dll`.

I then found I had to update php with the imap function and I did so. Now, the imap functions works in php interactive inside Terminal, but I can't get it to work in the browser. I'm assuming I have to somehow load it in the Apache Config files but I can't seem to find how to do so.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to restart Apache to reload the PHP module with the new configuration.  The command line PHP starts a new PHP instance each time with the latest configuration, whereas the PHP extension running in Apache is separate, and only loads new configuration setting when Apache itself is restarted.

Assuming you're running on Windows based on the .dll extension, so `apachectl restart` or `apache2ctl restart` may work, or the installer you used may have a tray app or other GUI tool that can do it for you.

If running on Linux `sudo service apache2 restart` or `sudo service httpd restart` depending on distribution.

Comment: I should have mentioned I am running OSX Mavericks, but `sudo apachectl resart` was the first thing I tried to do. This did nothing. You might also find it interesting that before the install I was able to run `sudo php restart` but afterwards it gave me an error `Could not open input file: restart`.

Because it didn't do anything when I restarted Apache, I'm thinking Apache may be pulling PHP from the wrong place. Where would I find the correct PHP module? Do I need to install a new module to handle the new install of PHP?

Comment: Uncommenting "extension=php_imap.dll" would only work on Windows.  Whatever you did to "update php with the imap function" has made changes to the php.ini used by the CLI process and not Apache.  Use phpinfo() to find where the PHP.ini for each is located and compare the two files.  Once the differences are resolved, restart apache again.  PHP is not a service, you can't "sudo php restart", all that does is run the PHP interpreter as root and ask it to process a file called "restart".

Comment: What differences might there be? I didn't have a php.ini for Apache file so I simply copied the one loaded in PHP interactive to /etc/php.ini (which is the one Apache uses) as I needed one anyway. This also did not work.

Comment: you can use `apachectl graceful` to load newly installed apache modules without restarting the apache service